# Separate Tkinter GUI classes into more meaningful ways

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make the following code meaningful as much as possible, using inheritance. The purpose is for learning. The App class is the most super class. And the Tabs class has inherited it. Can I make the following code more meaningful and break it for more better classes? Instead of creating notebook = self.notebook for all the Tabs class methods, can't I initialize it in the Tab class's **init** method. When it is done notebook was non recognizable. I need all the tabs background color to be same. Hence, if I can mention it in the Tabs class's init method and convert its other methods(about, ..., visualize) into child classes of Tabs class, will it be a good suggestion? kindly help

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter.font import Font


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # intializing the window
        
        self.title("Data Visualization")

        # configuring size of the window
        self.geometry('800x650')
        
        # this removes the maximize button
        self.resizable(0,0)

        # Styling the tabs
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.theme_create('pastel', settings={
            ".": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": '#ffffff', # All except tabs
                    "font": 'red'
                }
            },
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {
                    "background":'#848a98', # Your margin color
                    "tabmargins": [5, 5, 4, 4], # margins: left, top, right, separator
                }
            },
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": '#d9ffcc', # tab color when not selected
                    "padding": [10, 2], # [space between text and horizontal tab-button border, space between text and vertical tab_button border]
                    "font":"white"
                },
                "map": {
                    "background": [("selected", '#ccffff')], # Tab color when selected
                    "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] # text margins
                }
            }
        })

        s.theme_use('pastel')
        #s.theme_use('default')
        s.configure('TNotebook.Tab', font=('URW Gothic L','13','bold'))
        #s.map("TNotebook", background= [("selected", "#ffffff")])
   

         #Create Tab Control
        
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        

    
class Tabs(App):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def about(self):
        
        my_font = Font(
            family = 'Arial',
            size = 15,
            weight = 'bold',
            slant = 'roman',
            underline = 0,
            overstrike = 0
        )
    
        my_font2 = Font(
            family = 'Arial',
            size = 11,
            #weight = 'bold',
            slant = 'roman',
            underline = 0,
            overstrike = 0
        )

        notebook = self.notebook
        f1 = tk.Frame(notebook)#,background="#FFFAF0")
        
                
        #logo
        logo = Image.open('airport.jpg')
        #Resize the Image using resize method
        resized_image= logo.resize((600,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
        logo_label = ttk.Label(f1,image=logo,relief="raised")
        logo_label.image = logo
        #logo_label.grid(column=3, row=0)
        logo_label.place(relx=0.12,rely=0.1) # using place
        notebook.add(f1, text="About" )
 
        
        # Tab1
        ttk.Label(f1, text="Airports, Airport-frequencies and Runways analysis", font=my_font).place(relx=0.2,rely=0.03)

        #text box
        
        text_box = tk.Text(f1, height =10,font=my_font2)
        text_box.insert(1.0,"""This application allows you to analyze Airports, Airport-frequencies and Runways of Europe.
        
        • Tab "Load and Save Actions" is to load the initial data set (which consists of three CSV files) and translate it into a suitable format. \n\n• Tab "Preprocess" is to clean and prepare the initial data set, managing inconsistences, \nerrors, missing values and any specific changes required. \n\n• Tab "Visualize" is to use the prepared data set to generate output and visualisations.""" )
        text_box.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
        text_box.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
        text_box.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.65)
        text_box.config(highlightthickness = 2, borderwidth=0,background='#FFFAFA')
        notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        
    def load_save(self):
        notebook = self.notebook
        f2 = tk.Frame(notebook,background="#ffffff")
        notebook.add(f2, text="Load and Save Actions" )
        
        
    def preprocess(self):
        notebook = self.notebook
        f3 = tk.Frame(notebook,background="#ffffff")
        notebook.add(f3, text="Preprocess" )
        
        
    def visualize(self):
        notebook = self.notebook
        f4 = tk.Frame(notebook,background="#ffffff")
        notebook.add(f4, text="Visualize" )
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    

    tabs=Tabs()
    tabs.about()
    tabs.load_save()
    tabs.preprocess()
    tabs.visualize()
    tabs.mainloop()
```

Comment: Um... yes, you can in fact refactor your code. What's the specific question? This seems a little opinion-based for SO. If you're asking us to fix your code's formatting, maybe this would be a better question for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first, specifically what's [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `Tabs` should **not** inherit from `App`. Inheritance is an *is a* relationship. If `Tabs` inherits from `App`, that means that `Tabs` *is a* `App`. Meaning, you now have two `Apps`: the original one plus a specialized version.

This is especially problematic with tkinter. Tkinter is designed to have exactly one instance of `Tk`, but you have one for `App` (since `App` *is a* `Tk`) plus one for every instance of `Tab`. This will cause behaviors that are unintuitive and not generally desireable.

Inheritance isn't for sharing data between objects. If `Tabs` needs access to data or functions in `App`, it should do so by calling functions or accessing data from the `App` instance itself.

A better structure is to create a custom class for a tab and then make instances of that class, rather than having functions that create the tab.

Here's an example where the instance of `app` is passed to each tab. The tab can then use `self.app` to call functions or access variables in `App`. The `Tab` class will create a frame in `app.notebook` with some common options.

By making each tab a class, it gives you a convenient way to encapsulate functions and data specific to each tab.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        ...
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.about_tab = AboutTab(app=self)
        self.load_save = LoadSaveTab(app=self)

class Tab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, app, label):
        # given an app, make this a child of app.notebook
        self.app = app
        super().__init__(app.notebook, background="#FFFAF0")
        self.app.notebook.add(self, text=label)

class AboutTab(Tab):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app, "About")

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the 'About' tab")
        label.pack(fill="both")
        ...

class LoadSaveTab(Tab):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app, "Load and Save")

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the 'Load and Save' tab")
        label.pack(fill="both")
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Got it Bryan... much clear... I will remove being inherited from App...